# Connecting a large number of I²S busses to a computer

Tags: i2s

I'd like to try designing a digital mixer using a [Raspberry Pi CM 4](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/cm4/cm4-datasheet.pdf). The first problem I'm facing is how to connect a large number of ADCs and DACs to the Pi. These converters have a resolution of 24 bits and a sample rate of 192 kHz. I'll start testing with a handful, but I want the possibility of connecting up to, say, 128 of them (although I might have to limit the sample rate to 96 or 48 kHz when using that many channels). 128 times 24 bits, 192k times a second equals a total data rate of ~590 MBit/s.

I assume the PCIe Gen2 x1 interface is the way to go, but I've got no idea how to connect these I²S busses to it. My first thought was to convert the PCIe interface to a couple USB 2.0 ports and connect these to a bunch of USB to I²S interfaces, but 1) I'd need a lot of USB hub ICs, 2) using USB to connect components on a PCB *feels* wrong to me, although I could be wrong, 3) I've found no I²S USB interfaces that support 192 kHz.

I've also thought about using microcontrollers to convert all the I²Ss to a couple of easier-to-interface SPI busses, but this seems like an overly complicated solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with I2S and audio processing to give a definitive answer but these bitrates seem rather high for a Pi. My instinct for a mixer of this size would be dedicated ICs or a suitably fast FPGA, with a *control* channel and perhaps a few audio channels to and from the Pi.

Comment: There are a couple of existing standards for transmitting large amounts of audio data over Ethernet. Look up "digital snake". You'll use one or more such units to do most of your data aggregation for you -- and at the same time, make the system easier to set up, use and tear down.

Comment: @nanofarad Good point. My current plan was to use 2 CMs, 1 for the audio processing and 1 to handle everything else (reading button/fader inputs, driving indicator LEDs, rendering the graphical interface, touchscreen input, ....). Example: This second Pi would get the fader positions, convert them to numbers between 0 and 1 (0 if mute is enabled), send these parameters to the other Pi (via ethernet?). (1/2)

Comment: The other Pi would run a loop at some fraction of the sampling frequency, get samples from the ADCs, multiply them with their respective volume, add them all together and send them to a DAC. I figured the Pi would be able to handle quite some data using a stripped-down OS, optimized multi-core code, some overclocking, and maybe even some GPU acceleration. (2/2)

Comment: @DaveTweed I was planning on adding some digital I/O (like AES50) anyway, but also want analog I/O both for directly connecting to the mixer and for fx inserts. These digital snakes also seem pretty expensive.

Comment: I think what you need to do is arrange the I2C inputs into a TDM stream to work with on the Pi. You could look at the PSOC I2C bus component (https://www.cypress.com/file/137371) which allows up to 10 input channels. However this increases your front end complexity with a bunch of PSOC 3's

Comment: @JackCreasey: We're talking about I2S here, not I2C -- very different.

Comment: @DaveTweed ...a typo ....I meant I2S, follow the link and you'll see I was talking about I2S, the PSOC I2S bus component.

Comment: As others have suggested you’ll need custom silicon or an fpga. If you have sources at different bit rates, these be upsampled before you can mix. If you want the mixing done in real time, then you’ll want some dsp to do that for you. More dsp if you want eq etc as well. Sit down and do some numbers and you might want to reconsider your specs. I’d be looking at a Zynq at a minimum. Raspi, not likely - at least not without a lot of help.

Comment: @Kartman I've got this annoying tendency of getting interested in projects that are usually done by a team of experienced people, as a simple self-taught electronics hobbyist :) I was hoping to avoid FPGAs to have as much flexibility in routing the signals (and because frankly I barely know what an FPGA is). Even if that means lowering sample rate and/or my overly ambitious channel count. Zynq looks interesting but much more complicated than a Pi. I'd already been looking for more powerful CM4 alternatives, but hadn't found any.

Comment: An FPGA is like a box of Lego bricks - you can basically do whatever you want, so 'flexibility' is up to you - you decide if you want many to one, one to many or many to many and everything in between. Start with mixing two channels. See what level of compute resource is required. Then you can scale that to whatever can be supported. I'd also suggest you research similar examples that have already been done - what hardware did they use? The first part of a project is to do your research.

Comment: An FPGA gives you *more* flexibility in routing signals, in a sense.